# Grafana prometheus set $__interval to 1s

Tags: prometheus, grafana

I now have my `$__interval` on 2s because when I try setting it to 1s it won't display the query anymore. Why is 2s the lowest I can go?

`irate(rx_bytes{instance="localhost:2000"}[2s])` works perfectly fine

`irate(rx_bytes{instance="localhost:2000"}[1s])` query just disappears

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prometheus calculates `irate(m[d])` at a timestamp `t` in the following way:

1. It selects raw samples on a time range `(t-d .. t]` for each series with the name `m`. Note that `t-d` isn't included in the time range.
2. It finds the last two samples - `(t1, v1)` and `(t2, v2)` on the selected time range per each matching series, where `t1` and `t2` are timestamps and `v1` and `v2` are values for the last two samples on the selected time range.
3. It calculates `irate=(v2-v1)/(t2-t1)` individually per each matching series.

As you can see, Prometheus can calculate `irate` if the selected time range contains at least two raw samples. Otherwise it returns empty result. So, it is likely the interval between samples in your case (aka scrape_interval) is greater or equal to 1s. So any time range `(t-1s .. t]` contains less than two samples.

The workaround is to use VictoriaMetrics (the project I work on). This is a Prometheus-like monitoring solution, which takes into account the previous raw sample just before the selected time range when calculating `irate` and `rate`, so it returns the expected result for small lookbehind windows in square brackets. See [this article](https://www.percona.com/blog/2020/02/28/better-prometheus-rate-function-with-victoriametrics/) for details.

P.S. it is recommended to use `rate()` instead of `irate()` in most cases, because `irate()` doesn't capture spikes - it just performs calculations based on an arbitrary set of raw samples. See [this article](https://valyala.medium.com/why-irate-from-prometheus-doesnt-capture-spikes-45f9896d7832) for details.